# yshift has no effect whatsoever

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm very confused by why this code doesn't work:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node (V) at (0,4) {$V$};
        \node (P) at (5,4) {$P$};
        \draw[thick] (V) -- ([yshift=10ex]P);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

This is the result:
[image: result]

As you can see, the arrow lands on P instead of being vertically shifted.

Comment: `([yshift=10ex]P.west)` might work.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is a situation where `--` and `to` do not have the same effect.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node (V) at (0,4) {$V$};
        \node (P) at (5,4) {$P$};
        \draw[thick] (V) to ([yshift=10ex]P);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1: I tried to find a related reference in the manual (`https://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgf`) but I failed. I just found that the `to` operation is described in the following section: `14.13 The To Path Operation` *"The `to` operation is used to add a user-defined path from the previous coordinate to the following coordinate."*.